# How do I exclude infrequent usernames from mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this code

```
SELECT usernames FROM table1
```

I want to select every `username` from `table1` however I want to exclude `usernames` that appear less then 5 times in `table2`.

So I want this: Select all usernames from table1, but exclude the ones that appear in less then 5 rows in table2.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
select table1.username 
from table1 
inner join (select username, 
count(*) as count from table2 
group by username 
having count > 5) as tmp 
on table1.username = tmp.username
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select username from table1 where username in
(
select username from (
select  username ,
count( * )
from table2 
group by username
having count( * ) > 5
) as x
);
```

tested on mysql 5.6 :[schema and code](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ea7152/1)